# Cannot find module: Ember-template-compiler after upgrading to 2.12.1

Tags: node.js, ember.js, npm, bower, ember-cli

After upgrading to Ember cli 2.12.1 I receive the following error, when trying to serve ember.

```
Cannot find module 'C:\Users\assaue\web\client\bower_components\ember\ember-template-compiler'
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\assaue\web\client\bower_components\ember\ember-template-compiler'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Class.htmlbarsOptions (C:\Users\assaue\web\client\node_modules\emberx-file-input\node_modules\ember-cli-htmlbars\ember-addon-main.js:72:25)
    at Object.toTree (C:\Users\assaue\web\client\node_modules\emberx-file-input\node_modules\ember-cli-htmlbars\ember-addon-main.js:31:43)
    at C:\Users\assaue\web\client\node_modules\ember-cli-preprocess-registry\preprocessors.js:180:26
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at processPlugins (C:\Users\assaue\web\client\node_modules\ember-cli-preprocess-registry\preprocessors.js:178:11)
    at module.exports.preprocessTemplates (C:\Users\assaue\web\client\node_modules\ember-cli-preprocess-registry\preprocessors.js:161:10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try updating below in package.json

```
"ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile": "^0.3.6"
```

Maybe any one of your addons might expect ember to be installed through bower.

Comment: already tried it but it doesn't worked. My Package.json look like this: http://pastebin.com/raw/8D1XAXXc

Comment: Why do you require this `"ember-template-compiler": "~1.3.0",` in package.json ?. you can remove this and try again.since that dependancy will be already bundled in ember-source

Comment: I deleted it from the package.json and tried it, but nothing changed. I still get the "Cannot find module" error

Comment: @AndreasSauer any of your addons might expect ember to installed through bower.. so you may need to remove one by and check . and if possible upgrade your addon to latest

Answer (score 0):

I think some of your addon listed in package.json requires ember js to be in bower directory. For my app, the addon was jquery-ui and it was referred as following.

```
  templateCompilerPath = this.project.bowerDirectory + '/ember/ember-template-compiler';
```

Add

> "ember": "2.13.0" ( Latest Version now )

in bower.json

Ember has moved ember package from bower to npm as ember-source, but still it doesn't work as expected because of third party addons 
when you don't have ember package in bower.json.

You may get `WARNING: Ember.js is now provided by node_module`ember-source`, please remove it from bower` in terminal when you run your ember app.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that the problem is in the `emberx-file-input` module judging from your log.

```
at Class.htmlbarsOptions (C:\Users\assaue\web\client\node_modules\emberx-file-input\node_modules\ember-cli-htmlbars\ember-addon-main.js:72:25)
```

Key fragment is *\emberx-file-input\node_modules\ember-cli-htmlbars*

It doesn't have the correct `ember-cli-htmlbars` yet and hence it throws the error. Try to find the version of the `emberx-file-input` which has the correct dependency.